# The origin of the verb "has" (the verb "have" for third-singular person)

Tags: etymology, verbs, history

From what I know, in Simple Present, all verbs are followed by *-s/es* if the subject is a third-singular person. Such as ***makes, matches, buys,*** and **studies**.

I also know that if the verb is ***have***, it becomes ***has*** if the subject is a third-singular person. And I'm wondering why it doesn't simply become ***haves***, just like other verbs.

> She ***has*** a book.

Why not: *She **haves** a book.*

So, my question is, what is the origin of the use of the verb ***has***? I'm guessing euphony has something to do with it, but I need to support my guess.

Comment: It may have something to do with the older conjugations "I have", "you hast", "he hath", "they have".

Comment: Seems like the "-th" ending was supplanted by "-s" . Here's a relevant passage: "There is some evidence that verbs written with this [-th] ending in Early Modern English were pronounced as if they ended in -s, which was common in speech before becoming common in writing" (https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-eth). This would mean "hath" shifts to "has".

Comment: @Silenus - you should write your comment up as an answer. :-)

Comment: @Silenus, I agree with Chappo. You should write your comment up as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As demanded in the comments, Silenius comment as answer:

> Seems like the "-th" ending was supplanted by "-s" . Here's a relevant passage: "There is some evidence that verbs written with this [-th] ending in Early Modern English were pronounced as if they ended in -s, which was common in speech before becoming common in writing" [[en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-eth](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/-eth)]. This would mean "hath" shifts to "has". – Silenus